# Action for scalar field with externally specified EM fields and gauge

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Consider the following Lagrangian for a complex scalar field $\Psi$ along with an electromagnetic environment,
$$\mathcal{L} = ([\partial_\mu - i e A_\mu] \Psi)^* [\partial^\mu - i e A^\mu]\Psi - V(\Psi^*\Psi) - F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu},$$
where $V$ can be any nice potential with a lower bound, such as the Mexican hat potential $V=-a|\Psi|^2+b|\Psi|^4$.

Considering a setup where an experimentalist has fixed the EM fields, how does one incorporate this fact into the action and obtain the equations of motion for $\Psi$? Additionally, how do we enforce a specified gauge in the equations of motion, for which we know $A_\mu$ corresponding to the fixed EM fields?

Comment: Evaluate the EL equations for $\mathbf \Psi$ and substitute in your known function for $A_\mu$ to get a fully defined differential equation. Theres no need to add a gauge since you aren't solving for $A_\mu$ and gauge has no effect on the EOM of $\mathbf \Psi$